# Command line hardware diagnostic tool for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, command-line, hardware, diagnostics

On the ##hardware irc channel somebody suggested me to use [hwinfo64](https://www.hwinfo.com/download.php) to discover a PC's hardware on Windows.

On a computer it hang at ATA/SCSI scan and afterwards the computer was not able to boot even. Fortunately it did not do persistent damage but it did this twice so I am reluctant to use it again.

I was told that hwinfo64 hang because that computer is having a faulty disk controller. I would like to have a hardware lookup tool that is non-invasive so would not freeze the computer, should any parts have some problem.

For figuring out data about the cpu, there is /proc/cpuinfo on Linux.

Is there a command-line tool for Windows, preferably open source, that emits a long text file with all the hardware parts in the machine, and causes the least harm?

Comment: `System Info` would have a report.

Answer (score 1):

[WinAudit](http://www.parmavex.co.uk/winaudit.html) is tool that you can definitely try. It is portable, open-source and has CLI.